# WSO2 Publisher APIs

Tags: curl, wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am working on WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0, 
I was trying out the Publisher APIs,
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Publisher+APIs

These APIs do not seem to work. I have downloaded, extracted and started API Manager 2.0.0 and was trying the above cURL's and none seems to work.

```
wso2am-2.0.0\bin>curl -X POST -c cookies http://localhost:9763/publisher/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag -d "action=login&username=admin&password=admin"
{"error" : false}
```

I have also tried create APIs cURL, it gives timeout error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response you've received for login call is the expected one. Here, a session cookie is saved in a file named `cookies` and it can be used in subsequent requests by giving `-b cookies`.

However, these are old APIs and will be deprecated soon. I recommend using [new REST APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/apidocs/publisher/).

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Can you please answer this question also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41219075/wso2-am-training-doc-issue

Comment: I tried to test my APIs with API console of API manager, it works well with my local machine IP URL but when I tried with localhost URL, it won't work. Any suggestion ?

Comment: How is it related to this answer?

Comment: It's question, not an answer. I looking for ans or suggestion,

Comment: Why is it not a separate question? Why a comment?