# WSO2 AM Training Doc Issue

Tags: api, wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am working on WSO2 API Manager Developer Fundamentals training doc(LabkitAPIM200DF.pdf). It can be download from https://github.com/wso2/WSO2-Training/releases/tag/APIM2.0.0DF,

Here I am trying to do Publisher API in page 53. I followed all steps but I am getting Forbidden error.

**1.** Create the `payload.json` file in the `[APIM_HOME]/bin` folder with the following text
and save:

```
{
 "callbackUrl": "www.google.lk",
 "clientName": "rest_api_publisher",
 "tokenScope": "Production",
 "owner": "admin",
 "grantType": "password refresh_token",
 "saasApp": true
}
```

**2.** Open a Command Line Interface.

**3.** Navigate to the {APIM_HOME/bin] folder using the command.

**4.** Give the **cURL** command for client registration. (Make sure the API Manager Server
is running before doing this).

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H 
    "Content-Type: application/json" -d 
    @payload.json http://localhost:9763/client-registration/v0.09/register

<!--
  ~ Copyright (c) 2016, WSO2 Inc. (http://www.wso2.org) All Rights Reserved.
  ~
  ~ WSO2 Inc. licenses this file to you under the Apache License,
  ~ Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
  ~
  -->

<html>
<head>
    <title>Error 403</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Error 403 - Forbidden</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version in the URL should be `v0.10`

```
http://localhost:9763/client-registration/v0.10/register
```